# Data added to Collection with a Join is not showing up?

Tags: collection

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('neq' => 'complete'))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('neq' => 'canceled'))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('neq' => 'closed'))
                ->addAttributeToSort('status', 'ASC')->load();

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array(
    'web' => $collection->getTable('web/web')),
    'web.order_original_id = main_table.entity_id',
    array(
        'web_duedate' => 'duedate',
        'web_ordertype_id' => 'ordertype_id',
        'web_shipbydate' => 'shipbydate',
    )
);

// Show the SQL created
echo $collection->getSelect();

SELECT `main_table`.*, `web`.`duedate` AS `web_duedate`,
     `web`.`ordertype_id` AS `web_ordertype_id`,
     `web`.`shipbydate` AS `web_shipbydate`
FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` 
LEFT JOIN `web` ON web.order_original_id = main_table.entity_id WHERE (status != 'complete') 
AND (status != 'canceled') AND (status != 'closed') ORDER BY status ASC
```

I then try to extract the data...

```
foreach ($collection as $order) {

    // $data = $order->getData();
    // var_dump($data);

    $shipDate = $order->getWebShipbydate();
    var_dump($shipDate);

}
```

My problem is, If I run the SQL that is created, it gives me all the results and data that I need.  However I am unable to get the `web_byshipdate` column in the collection data, this is a table that is `JOINed` on but my code below does not allow me to access it.  Also if I `var_dump` the result, it shows all the columns in the result up until the ship date columns that are added on.  IT's as if they are missing.

This is confusing since running the war SQL does include those columns.
 Anyone have any suggestions on how to get the data that is added on with the JOIN?

**UPDATE**

Running `var_dump($order->debug());` outputs this below for each record.  `paypal_ipn_customer_notified` is the last key, so it is not including the JOINED Table  in this output.

```
array(76) {
  ["entity_id"]=>
  string(3) "788"
  ["state"]=>
  string(10) "processing"
  ["status"]=>
  string(8) "assembly"
  ["protect_code"]=>
  string(6) "99728f"
  ["shipping_description"]=>
  string(20) "Free Shipping - Free"
  ["is_virtual"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["store_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["customer_id"]=>
  string(3) "705"
  ["base_discount_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_discount_invoiced"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_grand_total"]=>
  string(9) "1250.0000"
  ["base_shipping_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_shipping_invoiced"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_shipping_tax_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_subtotal"]=>
  string(9) "1250.0000"
  ["base_subtotal_invoiced"]=>
  string(9) "1250.0000"
  ["base_tax_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_tax_invoiced"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_to_global_rate"]=>
  string(6) "1.0000"
  ["base_to_order_rate"]=>
  string(6) "1.0000"
  ["base_total_invoiced"]=>
  string(9) "1250.0000"
  ["base_total_invoiced_cost"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_total_paid"]=>
  string(9) "1250.0000"
  ["discount_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["discount_invoiced"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["grand_total"]=>
  string(9) "1250.0000"
  ["shipping_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["shipping_invoiced"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["shipping_tax_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["store_to_base_rate"]=>
  string(6) "1.0000"
  ["store_to_order_rate"]=>
  string(6) "1.0000"
  ["subtotal"]=>
  string(9) "1250.0000"
  ["subtotal_invoiced"]=>
  string(9) "1250.0000"
  ["tax_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["tax_invoiced"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["total_invoiced"]=>
  string(9) "1250.0000"
  ["total_paid"]=>
  string(9) "1250.0000"
  ["total_qty_ordered"]=>
  string(6) "1.0000"
  ["customer_is_guest"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["customer_note_notify"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["billing_address_id"]=>
  string(4) "1575"
  ["customer_group_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["email_sent"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["quote_id"]=>
  string(4) "1800"
  ["shipping_address_id"]=>
  string(4) "1576"
  ["base_shipping_discount_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_subtotal_incl_tax"]=>
  string(9) "1250.0000"
  ["base_total_due"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["shipping_discount_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["subtotal_incl_tax"]=>
  string(9) "1250.0000"
  ["total_due"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["weight"]=>
  string(6) "4.0000"
  ["increment_id"]=>
  string(9) "100000694"
  ["base_currency_code"]=>
  string(3) "USD"
  ["customer_email"]=>
  string(17) "newerpass@aol.com"
  ["customer_firstname"]=>
  string(4) "Don "
  ["customer_lastname"]=>
  string(7) "Wallace"
  ["global_currency_code"]=>
  string(3) "USD"
  ["order_currency_code"]=>
  string(3) "USD"
  ["remote_ip"]=>
  string(14) "108.178.106.25"
  ["shipping_method"]=>
  string(25) "freeshipping_freeshipping"
  ["store_currency_code"]=>
  string(3) "USD"
  ["store_name"]=>
  string(50) "Main Website
Main Website Store
Default Store View"
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(19) "2013-06-28 20:14:30"
  ["updated_at"]=>
  string(19) "2013-09-09 15:08:12"
  ["total_item_count"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["hidden_tax_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_hidden_tax_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["shipping_hidden_tax_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["hidden_tax_invoiced"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_hidden_tax_invoiced"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["shipping_incl_tax"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_shipping_incl_tax"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["paypal_ipn_customer_notified"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are loading collection with `->load()` first and joining tables afterwards.

In fact you don't need to call `->load()` at all as the collection will be automatically loaded on the first iteration of `foreach` loop.

Thanks to [MagePsycho](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/517/magepsycho) for the hint.

Additionally you can simplify this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('neq' => 'complete'))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('neq' => 'canceled'))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('neq' => 'closed'))
            ->addAttributeToSort('status', 'ASC');
```

into:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('nin' => array('complete', 'canceled', 'closed'))
            ->addAttributeToSort('status', 'ASC');
```

Comment: is $collection...->load() really necessary here?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is the issue. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to simplify it first without specifying columns on the JOIN, so remove this part

```
array(
    'web_duedate' => 'duedate',
    'web_ordertype_id' => 'ordertype_id',
    'web_shipbydate' => 'shipbydate',
)
```

and then use `$order->getShipbydate();`

What is the output of `var_dump($order->debug());`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I removed the array from my JOIN.  I then tried running `var_dump($order->debug());` I have added the output from that to my question above.  It seems it is not including the Joined table's columns into that result.  Also `$order->getShipbydate();` is returning null for everything